# Get two columns (Images Stacked over Text) to sit properly next to each other

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010

This is an error which only occurs in Outlook 2010. This email template seems to work on 90% of devices and browsers.

The graphic below is an example of how it looks in Outlook 2010. The crude blue draw over is intended to show how it should look. You can also view the fiddle for the entire code which displays that section how it is supposed to be displayed.

http://postimg.org/image/zacxr5acr/

Here's the full fiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/Nexus1234/bxp14vcw/

Note - the below sample code is only the relevant section and sending this on its own in an email doesn't cause the issue, it's somewhere within the complete html which is in the jsfiddle

```
<!-- Two Column (Images Stacked over Text) -->

      <table align="center" bgcolor="#EEEEED" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing=
      "0" class="deviceWidth" width="580">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="center" style="padding:10px 0 0 5px">
              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class=
              "deviceWidth" width="49%">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0">
                      <img alt="" class="deviceWidth" src=
                      "https://mailerdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/i2in/email_assets/108/forum.jpg"
                      style=
                      "border-radius: 4px; width: 267px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; height: 200px;" /></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td style=
                    "font-size: 12px; color: #6f6f6f; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-family: arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 24px; vertical-align: top; padding:10px 8px 10px 8px">
                    <table style="width:100%;border-bottom: 1px solid #333">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="padding:0 10px 10px 5px" valign="top">
                            <img alt="" id="circle" src=
                            "https://mailerdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/i2in/email_assets/108/point.png"
                            style=
                            "border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; float: left; width: 40px; height: 40px;" /></td>

                            <td style="padding:0 10px 10px 0" valign="middle">
                              <h1 style=
                              "text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: #363636; font-weight: bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif">
                              The Roman Forum<br />
                              &nbsp;</h1>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>

                      <p><span style=
                      "font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif;">Here,
                      in a small space hemmed in by the great rocks of the Capitoline
                      and Palatine hills, the greatest names of Roman history fought
                      for power and prestige. Amidst an extraordinary concentration
                      of famed and marvellous buildings jostling for space, you will
                      walk where Antony spoke over Caesar&#8217;s body, Cicero
                      delivered stinging orations and the legions processed in
                      triumph.</span></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class=
              "deviceWidth" width="49%">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0">
                      <img alt="" class="deviceWidth" src=
                      "https://mailerdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/i2in/email_assets/108/villa-deste-tivoli.jpg"
                      style=
                      "border-radius: 4px; width: 267px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; height: 200px;" /></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td style=
                    "font-size: 12px; color: #6f6f6f; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-family: arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 24px; vertical-align: top; padding:10px 8px 10px 8px">
                    <table style="border-bottom: 1px solid #333">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="padding:0 10px 10px 5px" valign="top">
                            <img alt="" id="circle" src=
                            "https://mailerdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/i2in/email_assets/108/point.png"
                            style=
                            "border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; float: left; width: 40px; height: 40px;" /></td>

                            <td style="padding:0 10px 10px 0" valign="middle">
                              <h1 style=
                              "text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: #363636; font-weight: bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif">
                              The Villa Adriana &amp; The Villa D'Este</h1>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>

                      <p><span style=
                      "font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif;">Experience
                      the opulence of two ages in a trip out to the inspiring
                      hillside retreat of Tivoli. In the morning, we visit the
                      massive, brilliantly preserved and sprawling villa of the
                      Emperor Hadrian, where luxury on an unparalleled scale centres
                      on a fantasy rendition of the River Nile. The afternoon is
                      spent amidst the fountains and gardens of the enchanting
                      Renaissance Villa d&#8217;Este.</span></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table><!-- End Two Column (Images Stacked over Text) -->
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to always keep in mind the 20px rule. Outlook loves to add spacing around tables, making aligned tables a hassle.

My usual equation is,
(Wrapper table - 20px) / 2.
Your example:
(580 - 20px) = 560 / 2.

Percentages are tricky, I would set your tables as a fixed width. Your deviceWidth class will handle your widths on mobile anyway.

I would suggest applying this too all of your aligned tables.
If that doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like it could be where I have been going wrong. I have been doing web design in general for a few years now but this was the first time I have been assigned the task of creating a cross browser and cross email template. It is certainly harder than I imagined. It really is a different kettle of fish to modern web design. Thanks for the advice, you may have just saved my skin!

Comment: No worries :) A lot of people underestimate email development, myself included when I first started. It was like learning HTML all over again :/